# Can someone clarify this implication

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm reading a finance book, and I saw this implication that I don't understand. I mean where this g function come from? If someone can clarify this I would appreciate. Thanks.

If a have a function like $f(x,t)$ and the following equation

$ \frac{d f}{f}=\sigma dx \Rightarrow lnf - lng(t)=\sigma x$

Comment: It's the 'constant' you get from integrating. Because you do everything wrt $x$, the constant still depends on $t$.

Comment: Thanks Simon, but why the constant depends on t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually are looking at is the equation

$$\frac{df(x,t)}{dx}=\sigma f(x,t)$$

One common trick of solving this, is abusing the notation and writing this as

$$\frac{df}{f}=\sigma dx$$

and then integrating both sides. This is what was done in the book. 
Note however that we are differentiating with respect to $x$, although the function depends on $x$ and $t$. One way of understanding this, is that you solve the equation for every possible $t$, one at a time. So imagine a fixed $t$ and solve the differential equation. You will get a constant from the integration. But for any 'other' given $t$ the constant you get, might be a different one. So if you look at the global picture, the constants depend on $t$. In other words, they form a function $g(t)$.

If you want to do a reality check and just convince yourself that the solution makes sense, rearrange the solution for $f$ and differentiate. You will see that the function $g(t)$ dies during the process.

Comment: Thanks!!! I got it now